# References on "classical" Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I was wondering if there were any good references on Riemannian geometry that do not utilize more modern manifold theory and differential forms (i.e. focus on the oft-considered "ugly" approach with coordinates and tensors). Is this considered more of a "physics" approach?

I just thought it would be nice to see the more classic approach while slogging through the definitions of the more standard books (like studying classical differential geometry in $\mathbb{R}^3$ before moving to more modern books).

Comment: Manifolds were invented for a reason, and most of it is readability... and no, in my experience physicists use modern notions, they just don't explain to the students what they mean :)

Comment: You're better off using manifolds ... Tensors are gross and many coordinate systems are unwieldy. It would be 'nice' to have a classic approach, but it would just be too messy.

Comment: Fair enough, haha. Thanks for the advice friends :)

Comment: Sure. Struik's and Kreyszig's books on differential geometry.

Comment: You might also try Eisenhart.